# How I change static IP address using Android Debug Bridge (ADB)?

Tags: android, static, ip, adb

From Android Debug Bridge (ADB), how can I change the static IP address of the device?
I am on `Android 4.01` and can't find a setting for it in settings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:
adb shell
ip addr add 192.168.3.162/24 dev eth1

netcfg is also useful to display the configuration

Persistent IP addresses are stored in the mysql database:

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
```

Comment: FYI, I had to disconnect from any Wi-Fi network and then delete the current ip addr listing before adding it again. (This was on Google Glass, dunno about other devices.)

You can use `ip addr help` to find out more info about that command.